# Manually Crash Kamailio in mi_xmlrpc module?

Tags: kamailio

I am beginner to the kamailio opensource project..i want to crash the kamailio manually to generate core file and debug it later ...I have tried using abort() and printing character array with integer identifier but no success..

can anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

First: note that MI control interface was deprecated many years ago and all related code was removed starting with Kamailio version 5.0.0 (released in February 2017) -- that included removal of mi_xmlrpc module. So you work on a very old release (v4.4.x or older), no longer maintained.

To your actual question: look at the cfgutils module, it implements the abort() function that should crash kamailio. Note also that you may not get the core dump file on some operating systems if you do not run kamailio under root (privileged) user and you do not have lifted the limit for core file size (use 'ulimit -c unlimited' before starting kamailio). Moreover, some applications such as apparmor can 'hide' the crash result.